# How do you use opengl functions?

Tags: xcode, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to build the source code provided for the book [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://www.mathfor3dgameprogramming.com). I've linked the OpenGL.Framework in "Build Phases" and included (not sure which one I need)

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

Now I get

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'Sqrt'
Use of undeclared identifier 'InverseSqrt'
Use of undeclared identifier 'fabs'
```

I'm guessing these have to do with not setting up OpenGL properly?
The author mentions using GLSL in the book but doesn't go into the details. I'm new to OpenGL.

Comment: None of these functions have anything to do with OpenGL. Everything related to OpenGL starts with a `GL_…` or a `gl…`

Comment: It sounds like this book is not a good place for a beginner to learn OpenGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not a xcode coder but in **C++** `fabs,sqrt` are in `math.h` and if `InverseSqrt` means `sqr` so you can try to do a fix like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#define Sqrt sqrt
#define InverseSqrt(x) (x*x)
```

some environments want this instead:

```
#include <math>
#define Sqrt sqrt
#define InverseSqrt(x) (x*x)
```

However as mentioned in the comment those functions have nothing to do with OpenGL so they are most likely used in some lib you have included/linked whatever ... and forgot to include some header you should ...

**[Edit1]**

If `InverseSqrt` means `1/sqrt(x)` as derhass suggested (english terminology feels sometimes weird) then use

```
#define InverseSqrt(x) (1/sqrt(x))
```

Comment: `InverseSqrt` usually means `1./sqrt(x)`

Comment: @derhass heh didn't think of that :) ... for me inverse is inverse not `1/x` had added edit ...

Answer (score 1):

`inversesqrt` (no caps) is a built in function in GLSL, while `fabs` is a function in C, and `sqrt` exists in both languages. Xcode can compile C/C++, but you must write code to compile GLSL.